# BluetoothGattDescriptor is always NULL

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, descriptor, gatt

My CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG is

```
public final static UUID CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG =  UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
```

I do this to change CHARACTERISTIC:

```
            BluetoothGatt mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this.context, false, mGattCallback);
            mBluetoothGatt.connect();


            BluetoothGattService mCustomService = bleScanner.getBluetoothGatt().getService(UUID.fromString(bleServiceUUID));
            if(mCustomService == null){
               return;
            }

            BluetoothGattCharacteristic mCharacteristic = mCustomService.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString(bleCharacteristicUUID));
            if(mReadCharacteristic == null){
                return;
            }
            String message = "myMessage";
            mCharacteristic.setValue(message.getBytes());

            if (!mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic)) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to write characteristic");
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Writed characteristic " + message);
            }
```

After that `characteristic` is changed on sensor, `onCharacteristicWrite` is called in `BluetoothGattCallback`

```
@Override
                public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {

                    if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {

                        if (!mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true)) {
                            DLog.e(TAG, "Notification Setup failed: "+characteristic.getUuid());
                        }

                        BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG);
                        if (descriptor!=null){
                            descriptor.setValue( BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
                            mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor1);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

BUT `descriptor` is always `NULL`. And `onCharacteristicChanged` is never called.
**Why? and is my CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG right?**

Comment: Any other information which you can share for this problem or have you resolved it somehow?

Comment: @Harpreet, see answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it was because some of devices (mine is Samsung E5 Android 4.3->updated to 5.1.1) are support BLE but doesn't support BluetoothGattDescriptor [0x2902](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/descriptors/Pages/DescriptorsHomePage.aspx) (see link)

to see all Descriptors which are supporter in device call this:

```
for (BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor:characteristic.getDescriptors()){
                    Log.e(TAG, "BluetoothGattDescriptor: "+descriptor.getUuid().toString());
                }
```

**[UPDATE]**
Some BLE devices doesn't support `Writed characteristics`, such as **iBeacon**